# Converting GET request to POST request

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, post

I'm building a application that communicates to a web service. Users passwords and sensitive information is going to be passed to a .php script. At the moment its just being sent over a GET request and - as I'm sure you guys will agree - is incredibly bad for security reasons.

Here is my script for sending info to a PHP script and then parsing it.

```
  NSData * houseData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:houseUrl];
NSString * password = _passwordText.text;
NSString * getDataURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://172.20.10.3:8888/finalproject/ios/login.php?username=%@&password=%@&token=%@", username, password,token];



NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:getDataURL];

NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

_jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
_citiesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];




for(int i = 0; i < _jsonArray.count; i++)
{
    code = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"code"];

}
```

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction for turning this into a POST request?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Get or post makes no difference from a security point of view. What matters is the use of SSL (https) and actually verifying the server identity from its certificate.

Comment: Ahhhh, okay. I'll stick with GET then. Its for my final year project at Uni, so there is no real world use. I just thought because the data is sent in the URL it would be easier to intercept.

Comment: I guess, kind of, as it may show up in logs, such as proxy logs and web server access logs. POST will prevent casual disclosure but on its own won't do anything to foil an eavesdropper.  Here is an example of posting - http://panditpakhurde.wordpress.com/2009/04/16/posting-data-to-url-in-objective-c/

Answer (score 0):

Changing from GET to POST wouldn't be a big win securitywise, but at least your parameters won't show up in proxy logs. Also, GET requests sometimes have length limitations (in servers, proxies).

Try this code (I've assumed that you get JSON data as response):

```
static NSString* const kDataURL  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://172.20.10.3:8888/finalproject/ios/login.php"];
static NSString* const kDataBody = @"?username=%@&password=%@&token=%@";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kDataUrl];
req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat:kDataBody, username, password, token];
[req setHTTPBody:[body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

[NSURLConnection
 sendAsynchronousRequest:req
 queue:queue
 completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                     NSData *data,
                     NSError *error) {

     if (error == nil && [data length] > 0) {
         id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                   options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                     error:nil];
         NSLog(@"JSON: %@", json);
     } else {
         NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
     }
 }];
```

Also, you might want to encode the `username`, `password` and `token` with `[token stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` or the following function:

```
- (NSString*)urlencode:(NSString*)str
{
    return (NSString*)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
        NULL,
        (__bridge CFStringRef) str,
        NULL,
        CFSTR(":/?@!$&'()*+,;="),
        kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
}
```

In the PHP script you don't have to change much - except making sure to use `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_GET` array.

Comment: Hey man thank you. I really appreciate this. Its for my final year project at uni. Hand in tomorrow, but I intend on taking the project on personally. I will have a good look through this code after hand in tomorrow. Really appreciate it!

Comment: Please tick the green mark if my code works for you.

Comment: I will do, absolutely